# How to check if the user has already logged into my app?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8

We want to integrate some FB-Features into our WP8 application with the C# Facebook Sdk http://facebooksdk.net/

I have integrated the Log-In flow with the Tutorial on http://facebooksdk.net/ and it works.

Now I want to check on each app-start, if the current user has already logged into my application. If the user has already logged into my app, he would have access to all FB-Features. If the user is not logged into my app, he would only see an "Login-Button" instead of the other features.

After some hours of investigaton i have found the following possibility:

1. Log-In the user
2. save the acess token to isolated storage
3. check on each app start if an acess token is stored

But I think thats not a good solution, because the user can remove the application and then the access token is invalid....

Did anybody has a solution for this?

Have a nice day!
With best regards, Matthias

Comment: Don't just check that the access token is stored, check weather that access token is valid by making a facebook graph api call, with which you can make sure weather user is connected with your application or not, and for checking user log-in, just implement a log-in flow for your application.